# Retrieve text file data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows

I am trying to retrieve data in a file that looks like this

> From: xxxxxxx Sent:   xxxxxx To:  xxxxxxx Subject:    Counter List
>
> [Model Name],ABC
>
> [Serial Number], xxxxxxxxxxx
>
> [Send Date],8888
>
> [Total Counter],00312697
>
> [Total Color Counter],00106667
>
> [Total Black Counter],00206030
>
> [Total Scan/Fax Counter],00035325
>
> [Operating Accumulation Time],  0.0, 13.8, 13.4, 18.0, 11.5, 10.9, 
>   9.8, 15.5, 13.0, 12.1, 17.0, 11.8
>
> [Energizing Accumulation Time],
>   0.0,727.7,718.2,728.6,667.5,735.2,738.6,627.8,674.8,575.2,500.2,379.3
>
> [Standing Accumulation Time], 
>   0.0,572.3,539.0,514.3,517.4,571.0,575.5,465.2,524.9,454.6,367.4,280.7
>
> [Power Saving Accumulation Time], 
>   0.0,141.6,165.9,196.4,138.5,153.3,153.2,147.1,136.8,108.5,115.9, 
>   86.8
>
> eof
>
> From: xxxxxxx Sent:   xxxxxx To:  xxxxxxx Subject:    Counter List
>
> [Model Name],ABC
>
> [Serial Number], xxxxxxxxxxx
>
> [Send Date],8888
>
> [Total Counter],00598310
>
> [Total Scan/Fax Counter],00002953
>
> eof

I want to start reading at "FROM" for each section, and display the data as separated by ','.
I am using a windows application C#

Please help

I currently have this

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
using (StreamReader sr = new Path.GetFullPath(openFileDialog1.FileName))) 
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string[] parts = sr.ReadLine().Split(','); 
        table.Rows.Add(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table; 
}
```

but its giving an error as the number of columns dont match –

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where exactly are you stuck? Can you please add your current code to your post?

Comment: I currently have this         DataTable table = new DataTable();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.GetFullPath(openFileDialog1.FileName)))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {

                    string[] parts = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    table.Rows.Add(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
                //dataGridView1.d;
            } but its giving an error as the number of columns dont match

Comment: Most of your lines have only one comma, so when you split them, `parts` will only have 2 items.

Comment: And that's my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is that most of your lines have only one comma, so `parts` only contains two items, and you're referencing indexes greater than the number of items in the array.

What's not completely clear to me is **how** you want the data displayed, since you appear to have multiple blocks of data (between the 'eof' lines) and some of the lines have multiple parts to them.

Here's one way to do it, where each block of data represents a row, and each line in the block represents a column.

Basically, you first add all the columns to the table. I did this manually, but it could be done by iterating over the file lines. Then, just read each line and add the column name portion (the part up to the first comma), and the data portion to a dataRow.

When we get to `eof`, add the dataRow to the dataTable, and when we get to the end of the file, add the dataTable as a datasource to your dataGridView:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("HeaderInfo");
    table.Columns.Add("Model Name");
    table.Columns.Add("Serial Number");
    table.Columns.Add("Send Date");
    table.Columns.Add("Total Counter");
    table.Columns.Add("Total Color Counter");
    table.Columns.Add("Total Black Counter");
    table.Columns.Add("Total Scan/Fax Counter");
    table.Columns.Add("Operating Accumulation Time");
    table.Columns.Add("Energizing Accumulation Time");
    table.Columns.Add("Standing Accumulation Time");
    table.Columns.Add("Power Saving Accumulation Time");

    var rowData = table.NewRow();
    var filePath = @"c:\public\temp\temp.txt";

    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
        .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)))
    {
        var thisLine = line.Trim();

        if (thisLine.StartsWith("eof", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // We've reached the end of a block, so add this row to our table
            table.Rows.Add(rowData);
            rowData = table.NewRow();
        }
        else if (thisLine.StartsWith("from", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // This line doesn't contain the built in column name, so I made one up
            rowData["HeaderInfo"] = thisLine;
        }
        else
        {
            var firstComma = thisLine.IndexOf(',');
            var columnName = thisLine.Substring(0, firstComma).Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
            rowData[columnName] = thisLine.Substring(firstComma + 1);
        }                               
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did a bit of twitching here and there. Works well so far, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 10 minute "hack" solution. You can take away what you need and fix up all the smelly string stuff...but it works

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"PATH_TO_FILE");
string[] singleContentCollection = contents.Split(new string[] { "eof" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var singleContent in singleContentCollection)
{
    string[] contentLines = singleContent.Split(new char[] { '[' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (var contentLine in contentLines)
    {
        string[] contentLineItems = contentLine.Split(new char[] { ']' }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        string Label = contentLineItems[0];

        Console.Write(Label.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty));


        if (contentLineItems.Length > 1)
        {
            Console.Write(" : ");


Console.Write(contentLineItems[1].TrimStart(',').Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty));
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("<----------    End Of Item   ------------>");
}
```

here is the output
[image]

Comment: Thank you, helped a lot.